# Subdomain redirect

Tags: subdomain

When I enter some dummy subdomain like test.mysite.com I always get my site no matter that that subdomain does not exist, where do I tweak that in WHM so that if that subdomain does not exist, user will get not found or something?

Comment: It might not be an option for your cPanel (depending on who your host is, might be best to directly ask your hosting site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though there is a wildcard entry in your DNS records, possibly a CNAME record that directs back to the root domain or the 'www' hostname.  Remove the wildcard record and any hostname which isn't otherwise defined will return an error to the user about not being able to find the website (or an ad page run by their DNS provider or Internet provider in some cases if they hijack NX DOMAIN responses).

The wildcard entry is a star (*) in most DNS editors and implementations.